# Does a monster's size have any effect on resources?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

Every time I kill a big monster, the game reports its size and keeps track of the smallest and largest of that species.  Do these sizes have any effect besides just a statistic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Size has no effect on what materials are gathered from the monster, but it does have an effect on monster stats. Larger monsters deal slightly more damage and a little bit more health and the opposite is true for small monsters. Certain event quests, however, are the exception to this rule. For example, there is an Uragaan hunting quest where the Uragaan in question is about the size of a Jaggi, yet has the exact same stats of an Uragaan of normal size.

Comment: I remember that event.  It was somewhat horrifying to attack something that tiny and having it murder me.